# Is there an nServiceBus sample for Pub/Sub with WCF?

Tags: nservicebus

It's a really common pattern and I'm finding it a nightmare to implement!

--

The WcfIntegration sample is almost what I'm looking for in that it receives messages via a WCF endpoint.  However, it receives messages back on itself.  I want a separate subscriber.

So what I'm trying to do is merge the WcfIntegration and pub/sub samples.

The real need is for a website to call a class library, which then calls the WCF endpoint of the publisher.

A subscriber then picks receives a message that the publisher publishes, and does whatever with it.

--

Rob

Comment: What do you mean by "with WCF" - is it that the communication between publishers and subscribers will be done over WCF?

Comment: Hi Udi, I've written a sample you can distribute in your Samples if you like. I'm just uploading it now and will post the d/l link.

Comment: I should mention that there is a bug in this which stops the message being picked up by the publisher - that's the bit I can't solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally got it to work here:-

http://code.google.com/p/nservicebus-wcf-pubsub/downloads/list

Anyone is welcome to improve the code.

Answer (score 1):

- You shouldn't need the interface `IEventMessageService`; NSB handles that for you.
- In my local example, I mapped the messages to myself. For you this would be:

  ```
  <UnicastBusConfig><MessageEndpointMappings>
  <add Messages="MyMessages" Endpoint="MyPublisherInputQueue"/>
  </MessageEndpointMappings></UnicastBusConfig>
  ```
- You also need to move your Publish to the actual handler. Right now, it is only happening once (at startup):

  ```
  public void Handle(EventMessage message)    
  {
      bus.Publish(message);
      bus.Return((int)ErrorCodes.None);
  }
  ```
- Make sure your infrastructure is primed, i.e. the queue is transactional, and MSDTC is running.

I'm willing to bet that since there is no mapping, once the service is called, it doesn't know where to put the messages (it calls `Bus.Send()` internally). I didn't look at the subscribers since that didn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: Hi Adam.  They IEventMessageService is in the NSB sample code, its needed by the client to call the WCF endpoint.  The unicastbusconfig can be set up to send to itself.  However, the handler picks up every message and republishes it - which means there's a loop going on and will just keep republishing the message once it receives it.

Comment: Also, that's the handler that the NSB sample provides.  Is there another one that I should be using?